# how to return string with re when formatting is different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

### Introduction to the problem

I have inputs in a .txt file and I want to 'extract' the values when a velocity is given.
Inputs have the form: velocity\t\val1\t\val2...\tvaln

```
[...]
16\t1\t0\n
1.0000\t9.3465\t8.9406\t35.9604\n
2.0000\t10.4654\t9.9456\t36.9107\n
3.0000\t11.1235\t10.9378\t37.1578\n
[...]
```

### What have I done

I have written a piece of code to return values when a velocity is requested:

```
def values(input,velocity):
   return re.findall("\n"+str(velocity)+".*",input)[-1][1:]
```

It works "backwards" because I want to ignore the first row from the inputs (16\t1\t0\n), this way if I call:

```
>>>values('inputs.txt',16)
>>>16.0000\t0.5646\t14.3658\t1.4782\n
```

But it has a big problem: if I call the function for 1, it returns the value for 19.0000

Since I thought all inputs would be in the same format I made a litte fix:

```
 def values(input,velocity):
   if velocity <= 5: #Because velocity goes to 50
       velocity = str(velocity)+'.0'
   return re.findall("\n"+velocity+".*",input)[-1][1:]
```

And it works pretty well, maybe is not the most beautiful (or efficient) way of do it but I'm a beginner.

### The problem

But with this code I have a problem and it is that sometimes inputs have this form:

```
[...]
16\t1\t0\n
1\t9.3465\t8.9406\t35.9604\n
2\t10.4654\t9.9456\t36.9107\n
3\t11.1235\t10.9378\t37.1578\n
[...]
```

And, of course my solution doesn't work

So, is there any pattern that fit both kinds of inputs?

Thank you for your help.

P.S. I have a solution using the function `split('\n')` and indexes but I would like to solve it with re library:

```
def values(input,velocity):    
    return input.split('\n)[velocity+1] #+1 to avoid first row
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: IS input a file handle? a string? a list?

Comment: @DirtyBit my expected output is: velocity\tval1\tval2...\tvaln

Comment: @ChrisDoyle input it is a .txt file but, for the example, it can be taken as string with \t separators between values of the same line

Comment: Ok  you could try using a positive look ahead to say that match only lines which after the velocity matches a `.` or a tab. That way if you give velocity of `1` it would match `\n1\t....` or `\n1.000` but it wont match `\n19.000`

Comment: Something like `results = re.findall(r"\n" + str(val) + r"(?=\.|\t).*", data)`

Comment: @Chris Doyle it works perfect! how can I mark your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive look ahead to check that after your velocity there is either a period or a tab. That will stop you picking up further numbers without hardcoding there must be `.0`. This means that velocity 1 will be able to match 1 or 1.xxxxx

```py
import re
from typing import List
def find_by_velocity(velocity: int, data: str) -> List[str]:
    return re.findall(r"\n" + str(velocity) + r"(?=\.|\t).*", data)

data = """16\t1\t0\n1\t9.3465\t8.9406\t35.9604\n2\t10.4654\t9.9456\t36.9107\n3\t11.1235\t10.9378\t37.1578\n16\t1\t0\n1.0000\t9.3465\t8.9406\t35.9604\n2.0000\t10.4654\t9.9456\t36.9107\n3.0000\t11.1235\t10.9378\t37.1578\n"""
print(find_by_velocity(1, data))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['\n1\t9.3465\t8.9406\t35.9604', '\n1.0000\t9.3465\t8.9406\t35.9604']
```